# Where to install Host Integration Server Development Tools?

Tags: biztalk

I'm trying to play with Host Integration Server. From the documents, it looks like to create a Visual Studio HIS project you need to have Visual Studio and HIS installed on the same machine.

My question is do you install Visual Studio on the server where you will be running HIS and work from there or do you install HIS on your development machine and work from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with BizTalk Server, the best experience is to run the full stack locally, preferably in a VM.

So, yes, you would install all HIS components locally, where you have Visual Studio installed.